# Is there a Outline (or OPML) plugin for Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2, outline

I am in search of a way to manage my OPMLs from Sublime Text. I know it is not thought to do that, but a simple plugin adding checkboxes and expand/collapse arrows should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find any plugin that handle OPML directly. But I use a [fork](https://github.com/poritsky/PlainTasksOF) of Plaintasks to have a simple list with checkboxes and collapsable section. And it is synced with Dropbox.

https://github.com/aziz/PlainTasks

[image: Plain Tasks screenshot]
[image: PlainTasksOF]

Comment: Does this plugin actually handle OPML files? I could not find any reference to OPML in the linked website.

Comment: No it doesn't. I was answering only this " but a simple plugin adding checkboxes and expand/collapse arrows should be enough." part of the question. Sorry my answer is not clear enough.