# Outline view in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, latex, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, outline

I've been advised to use SublimeText and I'm giving it a try.
When I take notes in a text file, I would like to structure it with a few levels of headers (in LaTeX, that would be sections and subsections).
The display should emphasize the headers, there should be a keyboard shortcut to transform a line into a header, and
I'd like a shortcut to display a table of contents, such that pressing eg enter on a header jumps to that part of the file.

I used a LaTeX mode for this, but I'm ready to switch to another lightweight format if needed, like markdown or html.
I've looked for LaTeX plugins like LaTeXing but they don't seem to fulfill my wishes.
Cde folding is nice, but I'd prefer to avoid having to indent the whole file python-style (it's fine in python, but I don't want it for all languages).

This question is related to [Is there a Outline (or OPML) plugin for Sublime Text 2?](https://superuser.com/questions/497764/is-there-a-outline-or-opml-plugin-for-sublime-text-2) but its posts do not answer my question.

There has been a proposal here, but no follow-up: https://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/83757-an-outline-pane/

Comment: If you're changing editors anyway, skip `subl` and go all the way to `emacs` :p. That's mostly a joke, but it does do outlining in arbitrary file modes. (if you wish to interpret this as a serious suggestion for some bizarre reason, I recommend using [bbatsov's emacs-prelude](//github.com/bbatsov/prelude) to get started - but be aware that going to emacs just for outlining is probably overkill)

Answer (score 1):

Using `CMD-R` (Mac) or `CTRL+R` (Windows) followed by `.` (you will see `@.` written in the input field) you will be able to list and jump between the root level functions of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Do display the entire method list hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Windows, or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Mac.